# Is the Find All References in Visual Studio good enough to judge if a piece of code is unused?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm refactoring a big C# project and it's only natural to find my *snowman's* unused dead code.

There's this function called FooBar() which *looks* useful since it has a bunch of code inside it. As is obvious, I was trying to find the references to this function using the "Find All References (F9)" option and it showed up empty-handed (even with the scope to Entire Solution).

Here is the function:

Class A has:

```
~
public virtual void FooBar(){

<function is empty>

}
~
```

I have a Class B with:

```
public override void FooBar(){

~<doing something important here>~

}
```

I've ran the "Find All References" on both these functions and nothing showed up. I'm assuming its safe to remove but worried if it is, indeed, used somewhere. **Apart from this**, I've used the "Find in Files" (with Solution-wide scope) for the method name and it showed up empty too.

**My question is**: Does "Find All References" obtain all the usages? Can it be relied upon to find and remove dead code if nothing shows up in its results?

**EDIT**:

This function is not part of an API and would not be called by any external code.

Comment: That´s the point of this tool. However pay attention on modifying the **public** api, if there are projects outside your solution that may use those members. "Find all references" will surely search within your solution. This the only safe way to remove public members is by making them `[Obsolete]`.

Comment: Could still be called through reflection. Will not necessarily be found, then.

Comment: Obviously, the solution won't be able to tell you if there are external projects using your code via the DLL.

Comment: "This function is not part of an API and would not be called by any external code." Then only the point abou reflection remains.

Comment: With external access out of the way: You have it in git don't you? I'd just remove it and see what the tests say, then run it and see if it crashes ... the more important it is the sooner it should crash. If it at all compiles.

Comment: @Fildor I like that you assume there are unit tests!

Comment: Use plaintext search to be completely sure. Of course, that only includes projects loaded right now (e.g. if the method can still be used in a project in another solution, and/or consuming project if this code is in a library)

Comment: @zaitsman That won't cover reflection

Comment: @DavidG Well i guess you're right, yes, a method can still be found without it's name and used.. but if the OP has that project it's a bit of a PITA to refactor anyway...

Comment: I usually do a "find in files" across the source tree, it's far more thorough. If that shows nothing and I know there are no other solutions referencing this source, then I pull the delete trigger.

Comment: @MarcE As written in the original post, I did in fact "Find in Files" across source tree without any results, which is why I wondered in the first place.

Comment: @cyfrost, sorry that wasn't clear. You said you "used the find function", which could have meant a number of things. Since you've done that I'd pull the trigger and wait for things to break!

Comment: @MarcE Apologies, I wrote Find instead of "Find in Files". I've edited the question for clarity :).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this is primarily opinion-based! We can see that the current answers are pointing out _facts_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are various reason this will not find code that relies on it.

1. It is a public API that is consumed by other projects.
2. The code is called by reflection.
3. The code is in files that are not analysed, for example Razor files are often skipped.

I'm sure there are more reasons beside these.

Comment: Much thanks! I'd be grateful if someone could, perhaps maybe, provide a sample snippet of code that would go unnoticed by "Find All References" but is, in fact, used by the reflection.

Comment: For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQC6yA (PS don't do this, there's almost certainly a better way!)

Comment: Thank you very much, that accurately explains my confusion. Also +1 for dotnetfiddle (I've only ever known a JSFiddle ;)).

Comment: I'm guessing, would doing a "Find in Files" across the entire source-tree with the method name be the last resort in finding its usage? Since it only supplies the method name as a string which is what I'm looking for in the Find.

Comment: Yes, that's the most (though still not completely) effective way. The only bug free way to do this is to have proper testing in place.

Answer (score 3):

It is useful, but don't rely completely on it.

Even if the "Find All References" does not show any usages, it is still possible that the method is used somewhere. Maybe via reflection, or dynamic objects, or if the code is inside a library, some outer application that is using this library can be using this method without Visual Studio knowing.

My advice is to research more thoroughly than just "Find All References".